# IGDB API Axios request returning undefined

Tags: javascript, api, axios

I building a Discord bot, and I want to query IGDB for the searched game and return some information. I'm currently just getting 'undefined' no matter what I search or change.

I'm using CORS-anywhere as a proxy. Not sure if that's the issue. How can I get the response to show data in the console like it does in Postman?

Here's my code:

````
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    if (message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
        const [CMD_NAME, ...args] = message.content
            .trim()
            .substring(PREFIX.length)
            .split(/\s+/);
        
        if (CMD_NAME === 'search') {
            if (args.length === 0) return message.reply('Please provide a game.');
            
            // Perform a GET request from the IGDB API through the cors-anywhere proxy.
            const proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'

            axios({
                url: `${proxyUrl}https://api-v3.igdb.com/games`,
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Origin': 'https://api-v3.igdb.com/games',
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'user-key': process.env.IGDB_USER_KEY
                },
                data: `fields name,first_release_date,platforms,cover,summary;search ${args};sort popularity desc;limit 1;`
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err.response.request._response);
            })
        }
    }
})```
````

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on igdb and pretty new with it. If I'm wrong let me know and i'll remove this :D

I think the headers should be different now that twitch auth is required.
You must call `https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token?` in order for you to get a `access_token` that you can then pass in your request's headers together with your `client_id`.

> Now that you have a Client ID and Client Secret you will be
> authenticating as a Twitch Developer using oauth2. Detailed
> information can be found on the Twitch Developer Docs.
>
> Doing so will give you an access token that is used for future
> requests to our API.
>
> Make a POST request to https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token with the
> following query string parameters, substituting your Client ID and
> Client Secret accordingly.
>
> `client_id=Client ID`
>
> `client_secret=Client Secret`
>
> `grant_type=client_credentials`

```
headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Client-ID':'your_client_id',
                        'Authorization':'Bearer access_token'
                    },
```

https://api-docs.igdb.com/?javascript#about